# React Creating Menu items by a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a menu with list items like below

```
   <MenuItem
      //className={this.classes.menuItem}
      onClick={this.handleClose}
    >
      <NavLink
        to={Constants.pagesURL+page}
        //className={this.classes.menuItemAnchor}
      >
        {Constants.pagesName+page}
      </NavLink>
    </MenuItem>
```

I want to wrap this with `menuItem(page)` function so within the page, all I need to do is `{this.menuItem('Home')} and {this.menuItem('Page1')}` to get menu items populated, easy and clean..

The struggle is I want the name I send when calling the function to be added to the Constant name.. For example, if I do `{this.menuItem('Home')}` then `{Constants.pagesName+page}` needs to be actually `{Constants.pagesNameHome}`..

I tried as above with adding + in front of `page` I send in, not working.. I tried `{Constants.pagesName[page]}` not working, I tried to create `let pageName = 'pagesName'+page;` then doing `{Constants.pagesName}` that didn't work either. How can I get this work?

As it is `{Constants.pagesURL+page}` I get 'undefinedHome' and 'undefinedPage1'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this was rather easy as I expected.. Playing around, I figured this is the way to go..

```
{Constants['pagesURL'+page]}
```

Works as a charm!

Full code:

```
   menuItem(page) {
      return(
        <MenuItem
          //className={this.classes.menuItem}
          onClick={this.handleClose}
        >
          <NavLink
            to={Constants['pagesURL'+page]}
            //className={this.classes.menuItemAnchor}
          >
            {Constants['pagesName'+page]}
          </NavLink>
        </MenuItem>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```js
const menuItem = (page) => `${Constants.pagesURL}${page}`;
```

Comment: Thank you @Dennis, I have a function set up for it, and with below change, I got it back to work.